# TextBox1_TextChanged_1 VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm busy with a form ( vb.net ) where Textbox1 is resulting a scan from a barcode. This works fine and it prints the things that must be printed with no problem at all.

code for the text change in form :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    print_DM.show()
```

---

On the main from where TextBox1 is handled, there is also a button to return to the main menu of my program with the following code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    menu.Show()   
    Me.Hide()    
    Me.Dispose()
```

The problem is that when I press the button to go back to the main menu my report is printed a second time.
How can I avoid this and make my code to print only once?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the code you've put here that indicates that your code should be printed twice. That said, I believe there might be a print command hidden somewhere in the `menu.Show()` method. Review that and I'm quite confident that your print issue will be solved.

Additionally, consider doing `Me.Close()` instead of `Me.Hide()` followed by `Me.Dispose()`. Closing the form hides and disposes it automatically so it saves you a bit of trouble. Also, when you use the `.Close()` method, you can easily add event handlers for the form's closing event (and even prevent the form from closing) if you desire.

Comment: Also remember, that after closing or disposing form, InvalidOperationException will be thrown when you try to use anything from that form, because it is getting disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Added a small control that checks if the textbox ( TB1 ) is empty or not
if it's empty it's doing noting , when the textbox ( TB1 ) contains data from the scanned barcode it print's my crystal report.

When the button has been clicked to return to the main menu the textbox TB1 is empty and no report will beprinted on lostfocus()

```
If TB1.Text <> "" Then
        Dim objRpt As New scanout
        objRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password")
        objRpt.SetDataSource(ps1.Tables(1))
        objRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)

    End If
```